# SCP with two different ports

Tags: scp

How can I use scp command to copy files between two remote servers from my local PC ?

remote server 1 : IP=67.12.21.133  & **port=6774**

remote server 2 : IP=67.129.242.40 & **port=6774**

**scp -rp -P 6774 denny@67.12.21.133:/home/denny/testapp1.txt  denny@67.129.242.40:**

It gives an error after giving password of 67.12.21.133 ,

**ssh: connect to host 67.129.242.40 port 22: Connection refused**

**lost connection**

Comment: I just tested that also, but only works for the first host. The second is locked to port 22.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `~/.ssh/config` to specify the ports to use for the hosts (and for setting many other nice things; check the man page `man ssh_config`):

```
# ~/.ssh/config

Host 67.12.21.133
  Port 6774

Host 67.129.242.40
  Port 6774
```

When doing this, you have to use the option `-3` to scp, which copies the files through your local machine. Otherwise, scp issues the scp command via ssh on the first host, so it actually runs

```
 ssh -p 6774 denny@67.12.21.133 scp -rp /home/denny/testapp1.txt denny@67.129.242.40:
```

and then the ~/.ssh/config of the first remote host (67.12.21.133) is used instead of your local one.

When you have setup your `~/.ssh/config` correctly, this should work:

```
scp -rp3 denny@67.12.21.133:/home/denny/testapp1.txt denny@67.129.242.40:
```

Of course, you can also copy the contents of the ~/.ssh/config file onto your first remote host, and then you can use scp without the `-3` option, which will probably speeden up the transfer.

Or you can use the trick that scp uses and use such a command line:

```
ssh -p 6774 denny@67.12.21.133 scp -rp -P 6774 /home/denny/testapp1.txt denny@67.129.242.40:
```

(Note the different case of the port parameter for ssh and scp: `ssh -p 6774` vs. `scp -P 6774`)

PS: I got this information from the OpenSSH bugzilla where I entered this as a bug: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2020

Comment: '-3' doesn't appear to be a valid option - I just get "scp: illegal option -- 3".

Answer (score 8):

I found no easy solution but you could try to use sshfs the following way:

```
mkdir /tmp/h1
mkdir /tmp/h2

sshfs -p 6774 user1@host1:/public /tmp/h1
sshfs -p 2211 user2@host2:/data/src /tmp/h2

cp /tmp/h1/files.* /tmp/h2

fusermount -u /tmp/h1
fusermount -u /tmp/h2
```

Another way could be to use ssh (actually not successfull tested):

```
ssh user1@host1 "cat /public/file.bin" | ssh user2@host2 "cat >/data/file.bin"
```

Currently I don't found the right way to enter the two passwords. It asks some times for the two passwords but doesn't accept anyone.
Maybe if you exchange the ssh keys between the hosts it works. Because you than don't need the passwords.

I hope this helps?
Thomas

Answer (score 6):

According to [this page](http://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/#specifying-a-port-with-scp) on the Linux Academy blog, you simply need to use the `-P 6774` option right before the second remote path as well:

```
scp -rp -P 6774 denny@67.12.21.133:/home/denny/testapp1.txt -P 6774 denny@67.129.242.40:
```

Each use of the `-P` flag applies only to the next location on the command line, not the entire command.  Any location that doesn't have a `-P` between it and the previous path (or the command name [`scp`]) defaults to the standard port (22).

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  It's a pity, because this seems the best solution.  The link is broken.

Comment: Just updated the link (though I forgot to log in first...).  Linux Academy decided to restructure their site.  Hope that helps, some!

Comment: If only this worked.  But I get `-P: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Tom - What system are you running this on? You might have a different implementation of `scp` than the one referenced here.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: @Tom Confirmed. I'm thinking in this case you're going to be stuck with setting up a per-user SSH config (in `~/.ssh/config`, usually) with the port numbers set in there., as suggested by the current top-voted answer. Not sure why this regression popped up, or when.

Answer (score 3):

A method working with the current version of OpenSSH is specifying the ports in the source and target URLs:

```
scp -3 scp://host1:port1//path/to/file  scp://host2:port2//path/to/file
```

Comment: This method also works if host1 and host2 can't see each other, but the machine from where the scp is being executed can see both (in my case with Cygwin, I did not need to specify the "-3" parameter)

Comment: This is the best answer! And it is also possible to mix the old host syntax with this new scp:// syntax in a single command. The -3 option is necessary only if hosts can't reach each other directly.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to transfer data from one server to another, use the SCP command.  To do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
scp -pr root@192.168.1.2:/path/to/files /destination/path
```

Note: The parameter -P can be used if you want to mention the port number.

Comment: you haven't read the question. He has a problem with the ports. you can set the first port, but nut the second with the -P parameter

Comment: @gajdipajti I didn't specify a port in my answer, and added it as a note.  The user also stated that he is using the same port.  Look at the Q.  2nd & 3rd lines :)

Comment: But it doesn't work that way, you will set the first with -P but the second will remain 22. Just give it a try. I am doing the tests at the moment, but still no working solutions.

Comment: You would only use the -P option if you're using a non standard port.